# every non-empty finite ordinal have a maximum element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that given $B \in \omega$ ,meaning $B$ is finite ordinal and $B \not= \emptyset $  then

$\exists A \in B  \forall x \in B (A=x  , x \in A) $

I know that because $B$ is ordinal then by definition of ordinal for every two sets $x,y$ in $B$ one of the following is true $x=y , x \in y , y \in x$

But i did think only in induction to solve it, please help with the proof.

Comment: Take the union of all $A\leq B$, or of all its elements, which is the same. It is an element of $B$ and it is not smaller than than all elements of $B$.

Comment: @acetone i did not follow , because i  think the union of all subsets of $B$ is equal to $B$, so what we gain from this ?!

Comment: Not the set containing all elements of $B$, but the union of the elements $\bigcup_{x\in B}x$.

Comment: Induction is also ok. $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ contains $\{\emptyset\}$. If $A$ has maximum $B$, then $A+1=A\cup\{A\}$ has maximum $A$, since $A\in A+1$ and for $X\in A+1$ either $X\in A$ ($X\leq A$) or $X\in \{A\}$ ($X=A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $x$ is the largest element of $\alpha$, then $s(x)$ is the largest element of $s(\alpha)$.

You can use this to construct the inductive step. The base step is easy since $\{0\}$ contains only one element.